# How do I run a bootstrap without an include?

Tags: php, autoload

I have the following bootstrap with an autoloader at the same level as my MVC folders.

```
-App
 --model
 --view
 --controller
 --public_html
 --bootstrap.php
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

function autoloader($class)
{
    $path = __DIR__.'/'.$class.'/'.$class.'.php';
    if (file_exists($path))
    {
        include $path;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

?>
```

What is an alternative to using an include/require `bootstrap.php` in `public_html/index.php`?
I looked at a number of snippets but they all incorporate namespaces which I don't want to use.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to do it without a framework, this is for learning purposed only, so no production. Having said that, I've seen this accomplished in CakePHP but couldn't figure out how...

Comment: I suppose you could setup AUTO PREPEND in your php.ini file but I don't think that really meets your requirements unless you only have one app per server.  Why exactly don't you just want to include the file?

Comment: @Cerad Only because it seems tedious and repetitive. If I wanted to add files to public_html, then I would have to use the same include over and over. It made sense to me that there would be a solution to this on a 'global' scope. But if best practice is using includes then that's what I'll do.

Comment: If you only have one php file under public_html(i.e. index.php) then that is the only file which needs the include.  Your controllers and what not won't need to include it.  This is a good read for designing you own framework: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to include that bootstrap to work with it. There is no other way.

if your problem is you don't want to include again and again, you may use .htaccess file which redirect all request to index.php... with this way, you only include your bootstrap file in index.php and then you can use your bootstrap codes in whole application files. put an .htaccess file like this near your index.php and include bootstrap file in index.php... after that you use your autoload function in your application files without include them manually. Note that you will need to add dispatcher/router to work with your .htaccess file... for detailed info you may check frameworks dispatching/routing mechanisms...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```